# Is the update server down?

Tags: updates

I can't update my ubuntu Oneiric. When I run `sudo apt-get update` I get a "Can't connect" message...

Thanks.

Comment: What server is trying to connect to when you run that command?

Comment: I've run updates and also did a fresh install on another computer in the last 2 hours.  The server I am hooked up to is business as usual.  Good luck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Possibly, but that's not a problem because there are over 300 servers all over the world. Check out Edit->Software Sources in the Software Center for available servers. It's advisable to pick a server near your geographic location for faster download speeds.